# cakephp: not understanding a statement similar to if else

Tags: cakephp

I found the following code in the cupcake forum plugin's forum_app_model.php:

```
/**
 * Validates two inputs against each other
 * @access public
 * @param array $data
 * @param string $confirmField
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isMatch($data, $confirmField) {
    $data = array_values($data);
    $var1 = $data[0];
    $var2 = (isset($this->data[$this->name][$confirmField])) ? $this->data[$this->name][$confirmField] : '';

   //== matches the values. Whereas === matches the values and the data type of the values
   //eg
    return ($var1 === $var2);
}
```

Can someone tell me on what is $var2 = (isset($this->data[$this->name][$confirmField])) ? $this->data[$this->name][$confirmField] : ''; in the above function? It looks like an if else stmt but i'm not understanding it.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's similar to:

```
if(isset($this->data[$this->name][$confirmField])) {
    $var2 = $this->data[$this->name][$confirmField];
}
else {
    $var2 = '';
}
```

See: [Ternary operator php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: yes, i was just trying to answer my own question with an answer similar to yours but it doesn't allow me to do so coz' i don't have more than 100points. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can consider this statement as

```
if(isset($this->data[$this->name][$confirmField])) 
{
    $var2 = $this->data[$this->name][$confirmField] 
}else{
    $var2 = '';
}
```

thanks